# TextMate Themes Missing

Tags: textmate

I recently tried installing a few new TextMate themes to toy around with and am **unable to use them** for some reason.  I double-clicked the tmTheme files to install them and TextMate launched, but the theme does not show up.

I also installed the tmThemes in **~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Themes**, quit TextMate, and relaunched.

Any ideas why my new themes aren't showing up?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange. Few things that came to my mind:

- Are you sure the tmThemes aren't corrupt? Where did you download them?
- You should be able to load theme files with the `Property List Editor.app` and it should display something like in the picture below. If not, something is wrong.

[image]

- If you double-click a Theme, is it successfully copied to `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Themes` if it wasn't there before?
- Make a backup of `~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.textmate.plist` and then delete this file. Restart TextMate and it will be reset to the defaults. Now, try to install the themes again. Do they show up?